# Custom label indicators on xAxis in MpAndroidChart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using a chart library called MPAndroidChart and it responds to most of my needs. However, I need to customize some parts.

1. I want to draw some indicator lines for labels on `xAxis` like this :

[image]

As I dug in, I could write a `CustomAxisRenderer` but it seems I need to copy most of the `super` class codes.

2. I want the min value to be drawn exactly on `xAxis`. This min value could be 0 or any other number as well.

[image]

How can this be done? Is it even possible to do it?

Any help or hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the first issue:

```
internal class IndicatorAxisRenderer(
    viewPortHandler: ViewPortHandler,
    xAxis: XAxis,
    trans: Transformer
) : XAxisRenderer(viewPortHandler, xAxis, trans) {

    private var indicatorWidth = 1f
    private var indicatorHeight = 1f

    private fun getXLabelPositions(): FloatArray {
        var i = 0
        val positions = FloatArray(mXAxis.mEntryCount * 2)
        val centeringEnabled = mXAxis.isCenterAxisLabelsEnabled
        while (i < positions.size) {
            if (centeringEnabled) {
                positions[i] = mXAxis.mCenteredEntries[i / 2]
            } else {
                positions[i] = mXAxis.mEntries[i / 2]
            }
            positions[i + 1] = 0f
            i += 2
        }
        mTrans.pointValuesToPixel(positions)
        return positions
    }

    override fun renderAxisLine(c: Canvas?) {
        super.renderAxisLine(c)
        val positions = getXLabelPositions()
        var i = 0
        while (i < positions.size) {
            val x = positions[i]
            if (mViewPortHandler.isInBoundsX(x)) {
                val y = mViewPortHandler.contentBottom()
                c?.drawLine(
                    x, y,
                    x, y + indicatorHeight,
                    mAxisLinePaint
                )
            }
            i += 2
        }
    }

    fun setIndicatorSize(width: Float, height: Float) {
        this.indicatorWidth = width
        this.indicatorHeight = height
    }
}
```

This code renders indicator lines on top of the xAxis.

Comment: Have you got usage of this class example?

Comment: @Dante313 Yes, it worked on my problem and it's still working on my previous project

Comment: That's cool. I'm actually implemented it too already. That saved me. Have you got code examples how are you actually creating instance of this class? :) By the way i guess in this class we don't have any place where we are using `indicatorWidth` variable :/

Comment: @Dante313 unfortunately I don't have an example available :(